# Gravity Forms Web API Update Entry

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm trying to use the Gravity Forms Web API to update an entry, this is the php code I have at the moment.

```
<?php
$api_key = '';
$private_key = '';
$method  = 'PUT';
$endpoint = 'https://www.website.co.uk/gravityformsapi/';
//$route = 'entries';
$route = 'entries/61';
$expires = strtotime('+60 mins');
$string_to_sign = sprintf('%s:%s:%s:%s', $api_key, $method, $route, $expires);
$sig = calculate_signature($string_to_sign, $private_key);

$api_call = $endpoint.$route.'?api_key='.$api_key.'&signature='.$sig.'&expires='.$expires;

//array of entries (each entry is an array with key=field id)
$entries = array(
array("status"=>"active","1.3"=>$_POST['first_name'],)
);

$ch = curl_init($api_call);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($entries));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

function calculate_signature($string, $private_key) {
    $hash = hash_hmac("sha1", $string, $private_key, true);
    $sig = rawurlencode(base64_encode($hash));
    return $sig;
};
?>
```

The response I'm getting is that is successfully updated the post, but instead of updating the post, it seems to delete the post. Can anyone see anything wrong with my code? If I refresh the page of the entry I edited on Wordpress I get this error.

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /data02/c6536622/public_html/wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/entry_detail.php on line 57
```

Is there anyway to get a log to find out what's going wrong using Gravity Forms, or WordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're updating a single entry just send the one entry instead of the collection. Also, send the whole entry or you'll end up deleting all the values for the missing fields.

Comment: Is there a way to update a single entry field value, without requiring to submit the whole entry data back? I just want to update a single field in my Gravity Forms entry, without affecting the rest of already existing field values.